# Escape special character in HQL query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, hql, special-characters

I have following code

```
public User findUser(){

    User user = null;
    String userName = "People's Democratic";

    String queryString = "SELECT user from User user where user.userName = :userName ";

    Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
    param.put("userName", userName);

    try {

        final Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
        Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> parameters = param.entrySet();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> parameter : parameters) {
            query.setParameter(parameter.getKey(), parameter.getValue());
        }

        user = (User) query.getSingleResult();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception in fetching user for the user = "+userName+ " and queryString = "+queryString, e);

        if (e instanceof NoResultException) {
            // User not found
        }
    }
     return user;
}
```

Though user with username = **People's Democratic** is present in User table , this code gives exception on line

> query.getSingleResult()

Following exception is thrown :

> javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException : Unable to find
>   com.domain.User with id .....

I  have tried escaping username with

> StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(userName)
>   Blockquote

but it didn't help.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the SQL that is being executed by your JPA provider.

Comment: In the code that you have posted the closing quote from queryString is missing, also assuming that userName is the Id in User entity one can assume that the entry doesn't exist in the DB table.

Comment: @garfield Edited In question.

Comment: @BillyFrost How to find that ?

Comment: In the LOG of your chosen JPA provider.